# Equivalent of include clause while creating non clustered index in sybase?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sybase

I searched on creating non clustered index with included columns for sybase database. But I don't think "include" is allowed while creating index. Is there any equivalent in sybase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Sybase doesn't have any equivalent to the `INCLUDE` statement.

Comment: So there is no concept of having included columns in non clustered index in sybase? Thanks for answer Simon

Comment: No, the equivalent would be just to have all the columns in the index, even the ones that aren't being searched/filtered on. Bit of a waste of space, but since it only affects internal (non-leaf nodes) of the B-tree index (and it's only useful on some indexes, not all), I can't see it being a high priority feature to be added.